# Linked in Company Insider plugin issue with ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, linkedin-api

I am embedding the linked in company insider within my website and this is not working in IE.

I have gone to the linked in website and loading directly from that but it does not work in IE

Has anyone else had this problem / know the fix?

this is the code I am using

```
<script src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/CompanyInsider" data-id="33432"></script>
```

thanks

Comment: Can you add a little bit more about what's going on?

Comment: the login with linked in appears the first time but then you can never see the people linked to you